# Using mod_rewrite how to Get the last 3 digits from a url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to get the last set of numbers from a random url, the url looks like:

/directory/directory2/a-b-c-d-123

a,b,c,d etc.. can be anything, numbers, letters but will always have dashes in between

We are using kohana for this project so there is some additional rewrite rules in play but this is what I have so far...

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /site/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b - [F,L]

#My Code Attempts Here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dealership/Listing/                 
RewriteRule ([0-9]*)$ index.php/dealership/Listing/$1     

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

I have tried a few dozen configurations, setups, and researched Google for a few hours with no specific answers.

I have been able to get the 123 all by itself but never with the directory still attached, also when I have tried a few configurations I end up in a endless loop and get an apache error.

The end result would be /directory/directory2/123

Thanks!

Comment: the regex is: `^/directory/directory2/([^\-]+)-([^\-]+)-([^\-]+)-([^\-]+)-(...)$`, a to d will be $1 to $4 and the last 3 will be $5.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, except I do not need any of the rest of the url only the last digits. I was able to get some matching working and eliminated the looping by watching for a pattern to only run the rule when it is there, RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /?dir1/dir2/([a-zA-Z0-9][-])+, which should match match only when the patten exists. the RewriteRule ([0-9]*)$ ... is getting the only the last numbers from the url.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine - why not make an answer?

Comment: @Xepoch: too easy to deserve rep points.

Comment: except the part where is it a random number of a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h combination, yours is a static setup. But it pointed in me the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]*)$ index.php/listing/$1
```

isn't useful, because it doesn't change `REQUEST_URI`, so the PHP won't see the rewritten `index.php/listing/123`, it will see the original `/listing/foo-123`. If you add the `[L]` flag, it will go into a loop, because the corresponding `ReqeuestCond` will continue to be true.

Typically you would pass URL bits to the script as parameters, for example

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]*)$ index.php?listing=$1 [L]
```

However, in this form it will not work, because `([0-9]*)$` matches the empty string on the end of any path, so it will cause two rewrites:

```
listing/foo-(123) → index.php?listing=123  # this is what you want ...
index.php()       → index.php?listing=     # ... but it gets rewritten
index.php()       → index.php?listing=     # no change so this is final
```

This happens because all rewrite rules are evaluated from the beginning after every rewrite (regardless of the `[L]` flag).

Thus, you need a more specific rule

```
RewriteRule ^listing/[^/]*-([0-9]*)$ index.php?listing=$1 [L]
```

This works on its own, but it would interact with your final rule, so add a condition on that to prevent it looping

```
RewriteCond $0 !^/index.php($|/)  # $0 is what the RewriteRule matched
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```